# new cl::Image2D allocates twice as much as expected

Tags: android, opencl

I allocate image via

```
cl::ImageFormat img_format(CL_RGBA, CL_HALF_FLOAT);
// image_shape[0] = 4096
// image_shape[1] = 576
new cl::Image2D(opencl_runtime_->context(),
                      CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, img_format,
                      image_shape[0], image_shape[1], 0, nullptr, &error);
```

I expect that with CL_RGBA and CL_HALF_FLOAT we need 8 bytes per pixel so 4096 * 576 * 8 is 18MB.

But when I look on the memory used by my app via

```
watch -n 0.1 adb shell dumpsys meminfo my_app
```

I see the difference about 37MB before and after allocation.

Does anyone know why the allocation is twice as much as I expect?
It's the same on different phones and image shapes.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android, but I'd verify that the memory figures you are seeing apply to physical (resident) memory and not e.g. address space use (virtual memory). It's entirely plausible that the image memory gets mapped to 2 different virtual address regions.

Comment: I would try allocate 10 more images and get the difference after the allocations. Then divide that number by 10. If the memory allocation per image is a bit smaller than 37 MB then there could be some overhead you have not accounted for. Also might be worthwhile trying a 1x1 sized image and see if there is any overhead (such as metadata) for Image2D

Comment: I've received an Android kernel patch from the manufacturer (I haven't had time to test it yet) which suggests that it might be a bug inside Android kernel.